# Flow hitting APEX CPU-time limit

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, cpulimit, cpu-time

we have a flow that gathers a number of account IDs downwards in the hierarchy and tries to update them based on their related records but we run into an APEX CPU limit issue once it gets to more than 4-5 records in the loop.

As you can in the flow overview below, it's a rather basic flow, see images for the entire thing below the error message.

Error message:

> We can't save this record because the “CSM Update Parent to Child V10
> CSM Change” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details.
> This error occurred when the flow tried to update records:
> CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER: We can't save this record because the
> “CSM Update Parent to Child V10 CSM Change” process failed. Give your
> Salesforce admin these details. This error occurred when the flow
> tried to update records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:
> Capitalization.AccountBeforeInsertUpdate: System.LimitException: Apex
> CPU time limit exceeded. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the
> SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to
> update records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:
> Capitalization.AccountBeforeInsertUpdate: System.LimitException: Apex
> CPU time limit exceeded. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the
> SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to
> update records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:
> Capitalization.AccountBeforeInsertUpdate: Sy... ExceptionCode values
> in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---... Error ID: 2332487-266616
> (-1241913226)

Flow Screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The Update Record element is going to initiate the Save process on the affected Account records, this in turn may initiate other DML. You need to dig into the debug log to see what runs upon Update Records to see where you have a too-expensive operation.

You can also consider delegating the updating to apex to run in an async context where you get 60 secs of CPU

Comment: It also depends how many records you have it in loop. We had similar issue where we were looping quite some number of records.We had to migrate to Apex batch for performing the operation.